# How to create Hive table with user specified number of records?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Is it possible to create a hive table with user-specified number of records?

For example, I want to create a table with x number of rows (where x is defined by the user). The table would have two columns 1. unique row id [could be auto-incremented] 2. Randomly generated String.

Is this possible using Hive?

Comment: P.s. there was another post of yours - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562705/how-to-generate-large-amount-of-data-using-mapreduce-process. I am curious why have you deleted it

Answer (score 1):

```
set N=7;

select  pe.i+1                                                                          as n 
       ,java_method ('org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils','randomAlphabetic',10) as str

from    (select 1) x 
        lateral view posexplode(split(space(${hiveconf:N}-1),' ')) pe as i,x
;
```

---

```
+---+------------+
| n |    str     |
+---+------------+
| 1 | udttBCmtxT |
| 2 | kkrMQmirSG |
| 3 | iYDABgXOvW |
| 4 | DKHKgtXKPS |
| 5 | ylebKcdcGj |
| 6 | DaujBCkCtz |
| 7 | VMaWfbtzFY |
+---+------------+
```

[posexplode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-posexplode)
[java_method](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/ReflectUDF)
[RandomStringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

Specifying limit on number of rows at the time of creating table may not be possible but , its possible to limit the number of rows that can be inserted into table using `LIMIT` clause

```
-- <filename:dbloader.sql> 

create table {hiveconf:TABLENAME} ( id int, string1 string)

insert into newtable 
select id,string1 from oldtable limit {hiveconf:ROWLIMIT};
```

and while submitting hive script -

```
hive --hiveconf TABLENAME='XYZ' --hiveconf ROWLIMIT=1000 -f dbloader.sql
```

as far as creating unique incremental id , you will have to write UDF for it.

Comment: You may use row_number() for incremental id.

Comment: This does not answer the question